# Match pattern unless match is an empty string

Tags: java, regex

I have a RegEx in Java that seems to work in all instances with content, however it is not just matching instances with content; it is also matching empty strings. Because of the data I'm matching, all "sections" of the RegEx must be optional, however there is no way that I know of to specify that if one section doesn't exist, the other section *must* exist, and vice versa (most of the time, both sections exist).

My current RegEx: `(-?[0-9]*)(x\\^?([0-9]*))?`

To repeat, this is working when it is matching existing characters. I just want to prevent it from matching an empty string between characters, which is throwing off the rest of my method.

Edit: Specific test string I'm using:
`"4x^5+x^4+2x^3-16x^2+3x-1000"`

Comment: Some sample data to go along with the regex would be nice.

Comment: This regex will match `-`, `x`, `x^`, `-0x^0`, ... among others. Is that really what you want?

Comment: And what you expect in each case

Comment: what do you want to match actually?give some example.

Comment: To support `A`, `B`, or `AB`, but not blank, regex would be `AB?|B`, meaning either 1) `A` with optional `B`, or 2) `B` without `A`.

Comment: As I said, apart from the empty string, it's matching as expected.  I know the input data format so I know all responses will be valid.  The correct matches are in the form `-2x^4` and include `2x^4`, `x^4`, `-x^4`, `2x`, `-2x`, `x`, `2`, etc.  As you may have noticed, they are terms of a polynomial. The input data will be valid.

Comment: I edited my post to include my test string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pattern

```
(?=[0-9x-])((?:-?[0-9]*)(?:x\\^?(?:[0-9]*))?)
```

by adding a look-ahead `(?=[0-9x-])` that must match something from your criteria
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/324)

Comment: That helped, but I still have empty matches after the last correct match.

Comment: It works!!!!! I've just changed it to capture two of the groups, but otherwise your amazing magical RegEx is working as it should!!!   Thank you so much!